# Do not create directory if already exists in php

Tags: php, directory

I am using the following to create a directory on an intranet app for each customer. The problem is, if the directory already exists I am getting the error :

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in     C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\customermgr\administrator\components\com_chronoforms\form_actions\custo    m_code\custom_code.php(18) : eval()'d code on line 11
 Failed to create directory...
```

Is it possible for the script to not create the directory if it already exists ?, either that or not show an error ?.

```
    <?php
    $customerID = $_GET['cfid'];

    /* wherever this particular script will be installed, I want to create a subfolder */ 

    /* Step 1. I need to know the absolute path to where I am now, ie where this script is running from...*/ 
    $thisdir = getcwd(); 

    /* Step 2. From this folder, I want to create a subfolder called "myfiles".  Also, I want to try and make this folder world-writable (CHMOD 0777). Tell me if success or failure... */ 

    if(mkdir($thisdir ."/customer-files/$customerID" , 0777)) 
    { 
       echo "Directory has been created successfully..."; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
       echo "Failed to create directory..."; 


    } 

    ?>
```

EDIT >>>>>>>>>>>>>

I have tried the following, but still no joy :-(

```
            <?php
            $customerID = $_GET['cfid'];
            $directory = "/customer-files/$customerID";
            if(file_exists($directory) && is_dir($directory)) { 
            }
            else {
            /* wherever this particular script will be installed, I want to create a subfolder */ 

            /* Step 1. I need to know the absolute path to where I am now, ie where this script is running from...*/ 
            $thisdir = getcwd(); 

            /* Step 2. From this folder, I want to create a subfolder called "myfiles".  Also, I want to try and make this folder world-writable (CHMOD 0777). Tell me if success or failure... */ 

            if(mkdir($thisdir ."/customer-files/$customerID" , 0777)) 
            { 
               echo "Directory has been created successfully..."; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
               echo "Failed to create directory..."; 


            } }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `is_dir` and/or `file_exists`, and only call `mkdir` if they returns false.

[edit]

Wait, did I just spot an `eval` in your error message?

Comment: I did. Completely random when to use an `_` in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is_dir` with `file_exists` to see if the directory exists:

```
if(file_exists($dirname) && is_dir($dirname)) {
```